# Is there a way to insert post data into html file loaded at a different address dynamically?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

I'm using an 'node.js' and 'express.js'. I wanna do like this:
1. If you send POST request with '/manage/payment/update', the post processing routine gets the query result statement.
2. I need to show that on '/' page. '/' shows index.html, which has a table.

In this case, how can I pass the data from post routine to index.html file?

```
router.post("/payment/update", (req, res) => {
    const ProductName = req.body.ProductName;
    const Price = req.body.Price;

    database
      .query("SELECT ProductName FROM screen")
      .then(rows => {
        console.log(rows);
        return JSON.stringify(rows).includes(ProductName);
      })
      .then(state => {
        state ? updateTable() : insertTable();
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
        res.send(err);
      });

    function updateTable() {
      var updateStatement = "UPDATE screen SET ".concat(
        "Amount = Amount + 1, TotalPrice = TotalPrice + ",
        Price,
        " WHERE ProductName = '",
        ProductName,
        "';"
      );

      database
        .query(updateStatement)
        .then(rows => {
          return database.query(
            "SELECT ProductName, Amount, TotalPrice FROM screen"
          );
        })
        .then(rows => {
          console.log(rows);
          //this is where i wanna send data into index.html
        })
        .catch(err => {
          console.log(err);
          res.send(err);
        });
    }

    function insertTable() {
      var insertStatement = "INSERT INTO screen(ProductName, Amount, TotalPrice) VALUES(".concat(
        "'",
        ProductName,
        "', ",
        1,
        ",",
        Price,
        ");"
      );

      database
        .query(insertStatement)
        .then(rows => {
          return database.query(
            "SELECT ProductName, Amount, TotalPrice FROM screen"
          );
        })
        .then(rows => {
          console.log(rows);
        //this is also i wanna send data into index.html
        })
        .catch(err => {
          console.log(err);
          res.send(err);
        });
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `redirect()` with query string for passing some data to other pages.

Example:

```
const url = require( 'url' );

res.redirect( url.format( {
    pathname: '/',
    query: {
        foo: 'bar',
        bar: 'foo'
    }
} ) );
```

or if you are using view engine. you can use `res.render()`. Something like `res.render(index.jade, data)`